# Показ страницы после загрузки всех объектов

Tags: javascript, html, кэширование

У нас есть страница index.html и там много фоток, которые долго загружаются.
Как мне сделать чтобы при загрузке фото было видно к примеру

```
<div class="Load"></div>
```

А после он пропадал с анимацией, И САМАЯ важная часть когда все фото сохранены в Кэше чтобы страница грузилась без анимации, при повторном обновлении

Comment: Более точно что нужно мне: "Нужно плавно показать(opacity) фон сайта при загрузке, если изображение не закэшировано, иначе - показать мгновенно."

Comment: А можно грубый код?

Comment: А какой тут пример кода может быть? Человек и спрашивает как это сделать, а не как поправить. Тут требуется просто схема того как подобное можно реализовать

Comment: по идее тут подойдет любой плагин по запросу "image lazy load", они работают примерно по одной схеме все: подгружают картинку через src, то есть дожидается загрузки картинки целиком, потом показывает, если картинка в кэше, то соответственно грузить не надо - отобразит сразу.

Comment: @Viktor, я обычно использую событие `onload`, пока картинка не загружена, показываю `loader`. так и страница не зависает. Правда в вашем случае, лучше для загрузки воспользоваться обычным словом вида "Загрузка", если использовать анимационную картинку, возможен лаг, если будет очень много картинок сразу грузиться.

Answer (score 0):

Срабатывает когда браузер загрузил все ресурсы, не важно из кэша или нет.

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(){console.log('loadedAllImages')});
```